# How to fill a colorbar in a channel with changing width in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

Let's assume I have a plot with two functions, `f(x)` and `g(x)` (see the graph below). Now I would like to fill the channel between these two curves with colormap such that the bottom is blue and the top is red. The middle part, colored yellow, is the transition from blue to red which is a function of the channel width. Can I use `colorbar` instead of yellow to show the transition from blue to red as a function of the channel width.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Here is the code ```\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 width=7cm,
 height=9cm,
 clip=false,
 xmin=0,xmax=20,
 ymin=0,ymax=40,
]
 
 \addplot [black,thick] table{
 x y
 5 0
 5 10
 14 30
 14 40
};

 \addplot [black,thick] table{
 x y
 10 0
 10 10
 16 30
 16 40
};
 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your code! (In the future, please add it to the question so that others do not have to add the line breaks that one loses by putting code in comments.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[width=7cm, height=9cm, clip=false, xmin=0,xmax=20, ymin=0,ymax=40,
    declare function={f(\y)=max(5,min(14,9*\y/20+1/2));
    g(\y)=max(10,min(16,6*\y/20+7));},
    view={0}{90},colorbar,
    /tikz/every pin edge/.style={stealth-,thin}] 
 \begin{scope}  
  \clip[variable=\y] plot[samples at={0,10,30,40}] ({f(\y)},\y)
   -- plot[samples at={40,30,10,0}] ({g(\y)},\y) -- cycle;
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,point meta={g(y)-f(y)},domain=5:16,
     domain y=0:40] {x};
 \end{scope}
 \draw[variable=\y] plot[samples at={0,10,30,40}] ({f(\y)},\y)
  -- plot[samples at={40,30,10,0}] ({g(\y)},\y) -- cycle;   
 \addplot3[black,thick,samples at={0,10,30,40},samples y=0] ({f(x)},x,0)
  coordinate[pos=0.55,pin=120:{$f(x)$}];
 \addplot3[black,thick,samples at={0,10,30,40},samples y=0] ({g(x)},x,0)
  coordinate[pos=0.45,pin=-60:{$g(x)$}];
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

This "inverts" the color bar:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[width=7cm, height=9cm, clip=false, xmin=0,xmax=20, ymin=0,ymax=40,
    declare function={f(\y)=max(5,min(14,9*\y/20+1/2));
    g(\y)=max(10,min(16,6*\y/20+7));},
    view={0}{90},colorbar,
    /tikz/every pin edge/.style={stealth-,thin},
    colorbar style={yticklabel={$\pgfmathparse{-1*\tick}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$}}] 
 \begin{scope}  
  \clip[variable=\y] plot[samples at={0,10,30,40}] ({f(\y)},\y)
   -- plot[samples at={40,30,10,0}] ({g(\y)},\y) -- cycle;
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,point meta={f(y)-g(y)},domain=5:16,
     domain y=0:40] {x};
 \end{scope}
 \draw[variable=\y] plot[samples at={0,10,30,40}] ({f(\y)},\y)
  -- plot[samples at={40,30,10,0}] ({g(\y)},\y) -- cycle;   
 \addplot3[black,thick,samples at={0,10,30,40},samples y=0] ({f(x)},x,0)
  coordinate[pos=0.55,pin=120:{$f(x)$}];
 \addplot3[black,thick,samples at={0,10,30,40},samples y=0] ({g(x)},x,0)
  coordinate[pos=0.45,pin=-60:{$g(x)$}];
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will do. Thank you very much!

Comment: Where do the numbers 1/2 and 7 come from in the `declare function`?

Comment: @Gagik These are the functions that run through the coordinates that you provided. So technically they come from solving linear equations. Otherwise `pgfplots` does not know how to compute the point meta.

Comment: How can I reverse the colorbar such that the red appears on the bottom and the blue on top. It would look more professional.

Comment: @Gagik Very simple: `point meta={f(y)-g(y)}`. The shading is determined by `point meta`. You can also use `point meta={exp(g(y)-f(y))}`, say, or any function.

Comment: That I already realized. What I meant was the reverse the colorbar itself, not the shading. I want the colorbar to start from red and decrease to blue.

Comment: Also, can I use a single color shading instead of `colormap{hot}`. Say, blue color only, and correlate the narrowing of the width with the intensity of the blue color. In the color it would go, for instance, from `blue!20=5` to `blue!80=2`.

Comment: @Gagik I see. You can just define your own colorbar, see section **4.7.6 Color Maps** of pgfplots manual v1.17. One basically can look up the definition of `hot` on p. 197, `\pgfplotsset{
colormap={hot}{color(0cm)=(blue); color(1cm)=(yellow); color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)} }`, and reverse or adjust it to the needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Changing the `point meta={g(y)-f(y)}` works except the colorbar appears with `-` signs. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Gagik Maybe `point meta={7+f(y)-g(y)}`?

Comment: No, it didn't work.

Comment: @Gagik It is a bit hard for me to guess what you precisely want and what precisely did not work. I added the output of my previous comment.

Comment: The colorbar is exactly how I want it, but the scale is incorrect now. It should be decreasing from 5 to 2 going up on the colorbar. You see what I mean?

Comment: @Gagik I added a version of that kind.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!